# Хеш с ключами-строками

Tags: c, хеширование

Новичек в работе с хешами. Вроде разобрался с хешированием чисел путем нахождения ключа делением значения на простое число. Но вот решил выполнить задание типа создание "телофонного справочника" - где ключ и значения - некие строки(до 20-ти символов). И тут я призадумался: а как работать со строками? Всмысле: у меня массив структур под этот справочник, но как выбирать нужный индекс массива на основе такой строки? Способ вроде: взять первую букву - слишком большое количество коллизий получится. Думал о генерировании числа на основе строки (вроде сложения всех букв), но в этом случае массив получится не сбалансированным: в начале и конце элементов будет мало, а в середине их распределение (скорее всего) будет не равномерным.

Comment: Взять хэш-функцию от строки, очевидно.

Comment: Для начала можно ознакомиться с [этим списком функций](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions). А вообще, тема интересная, затягивающая...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возьмите реализацию из [java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java). Если грубо - в цикле символ умножаем на 31 и добавляем следующий. А в конце можно поделить на размер Вашего хеша.

```
int hash(const char* s)
{
    int l = strlen(s);
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        h = h*31+s[i];
    }
    return h;
}
```

с длинными строками нужно  быть аккуратно.

добавил в конец деление по модулю 37 и прогнал через него /usr/share/dict/words (словарь английских слов на 234к слов). отклонение значений от среднего - 3.5% - то есть, достаточно равномерно.

Comment: А вы намеренно использовали знаковый тип?

Comment: Просто скопировано с Java. Без злого умысла. И о длинных строках я предупредил.

Comment: Просто стало интересно, это я что-то упустил или "так получилось". Я всегда использовал для хэшей беззнаковые типы.

Comment: Но и сам char скорее всего знаковый, так что там много чего интересного в любом случае.